# Signal Not Emitted when selecting tab in Pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, tabbar, tabwidget

I have a tab widget created with 3 tabs in it. I need to emit signals when I change the tab, Looking at the pyQt documentation currentChanged() is the signal that is emitted on Changing the tab but it does  not work for me. So need your help on  understanding the same,

MY code is as follows:

```
main_tab_widget = QTabWidget()

    #Creating Tabs
    self.run_tab = QWidget()
    self.cc_tab = QWidget()
    self.result_tab = QWidget()

    #Adding Tabs to Tab Widget
    main_tab_widget.addTab(self.run_tab, "RUN")
    main_tab_widget.addTab(self.cc_tab, "Config Creator")
    main_tab_widget.addTab(self.result_tab, "Result")

    #Layout Creation
    main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    main_layout.addWidget(main_tab_widget)

    self.connect(self.cc_tab, SIGNAL('currentChanged(int)'), self.pseudofunction)
    self.RunTab()
    self.setLayout(main_layout)
    #self.configcreatortab()
    #self.resulttab()

def pseudofunction(self):
    print 'Inside Pseudo Function'
```

Comment: It is considered good manners to accept answers on your questions! Consider to consult http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/whats-an-answer-in-stack-overflow-culture. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to wire up the `currentChanged` signal from the wrong object.  `main_tab_object` is the QTabWidget that emits this signal, but you're attempting to wire up this signal from `self.cc_tab`, a QWidget in one of the tabs.

Replace the line

```
    self.connect(self.cc_tab, SIGNAL('currentChanged(int)'), self.pseudofunction)
```

with

```
    self.connect(main_tab_widget, SIGNAL('currentChanged(int)'), self.pseudofunction)
```

**EDIT**: There is no way to use the signals/slots mechanism to connect a different function to each tab of a QTabWidget.  If you want to call different functions when different tabs are selected, you'll have to write another function that calls the relevant function depending on which tab was selected.  For example:

```
def selector(self, selected_index):
    if selected_index == 0:
        self.some_function_for_run_tab()
    elif selected_index == 1:
        self.some_function_for_cc_tab()
    elif selected_index == 2:
        self.some_function_for_result_tab()
```

You then connect the `currentChanged` signal of the QTabWidget to this function.

You are correct that QTabBar also has the `currentChanged` signal, but your usage of it in your second comment, by replacing `QWidget()` with `QTabBar()` in your code above, will not achieve what you want.

A QTabBar acts only as the bar that contains a collection of tabs.  (In fact, the QTabWidget uses a QTabBar internally for its tab bar.)  So, putting a QTabBar within a QTabWidget gives you tabs within tabs.  I don't believe this is what you want.  Furthermore I suspect you're not adding any tabs to the QTabBars.  The QTabBars do have the `currentChanged` signal, and your code will correctly connect these signals, but these signals will never fire because the QTabBars contain no tabs to change.

The fact that these QTabBars may themselves be inside a QTabWidget is irrelevant.  They only see changes to their own set of tabs and hence can only fire signals for changes to their own set of tabs.

Comment: But I would like to call different functions on selection on different tabs. But the above solution is tied with the tab_widget where as I would like that to be tied with tabs. essentially 3 functions for 3 tabs.. I looked at QTabBar and it also says that when the tab is changed currentChanged() signal is emitted. please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: I Tried defining the tabs as:                                      self.run_tab = QTabBar()
        self.cc_tab = QTabBar()
        self.result_tab = QTabBar()
        
        #Adding Tabs to TabWidget
        main_tab_widget.addTab(self.run_tab, "RUN")
        main_tab_widget.addTab(self.cc_tab, "Config Creator")
        main_tab_widget.addTab(self.result_tab, "Results") and tried connecting to signal currentChanged(int) but even then it did not..

Comment: oh.. thanks for the detailed explanation. I now understand it better. I will try the solution suggested.. THanks again for all your help.